# Realmのマイグレーション後のApp Storeでのアップデートの挙動について

Tags: realm

初めてSwiftとRealmで本格的にプログラムを書き、iPhoneアプリをなんとかApp Storeでリリースできましたが、Realmの処理方法を変更したいと考えています。

マイグレーション処理を挿入し、Xcodeでビルドアップしたところ、こんなエラーが表示されました。

```
Property 'hoge' has been added to latest object model.
```

とりあえずは、アプリを丸ごと削除して再ビルドアップすることで問題はクリアできましたが、ふと、思ったのは新バージョンをApp Storeにアップロードし、ユーザーがアップデートした場合も
このエラーが発生しないのだろうかということです。

もし自分が考えたようにエラーが出てユーザーがアプリを削除、再インストールするとなると、それまで登録していたデータがなくなるのは目に見えてるのですが、実際の挙動は問題なくアップデートできるのでしょうか？

サンプルのコードです。

```
// DataModel.swift
import RealmSwift
class event: Object {
    dynamic var eventID:Int = 0
    dynamic var eventTitle:String?

    // 新しく追加するプロパティ
    dynamic var hoge = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "eventID"
    }
}

// AppDelegate.swift
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {        
    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
            }
    })
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

    return true
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("appWillEnterForeground", object: nil)
}

// ViewController
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var realmURL:NSURL?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setRealmURL()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.viewWillEnterForeground(_:)), name: "appWillEnterForeground", object: nil)

        let realm = try! Realm(fileURL: realmURL!)
        let rlm = event()
        rlm.eventID = 0
        rlm.eventTitle = "First Title"
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(rlm, update: true)
        }

        print(realm.objects(event))
    }

    func setRealmURL() {
        var fileName = ""
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let fileNum = defaults.integerForKey("realmFileNum")

        if fileNum == 0 {
            fileName = "f0.realm"
        } else {
            fileName = "f1.realm"
        }

        var config = Realm.Configuration()
        config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

        realmURL = config.fileURL!
    }

    func compactionFile(URL: NSURL) {
        let oldRealmURL = URL
        var newRealmURL:NSURL!

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let fileNum = defaults.integerForKey("realmFileNum")
        if fileNum == 0 {
            newRealmURL = oldRealmURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("f1.realm")
            defaults.setInteger(1, forKey: "realmFileNum")
        } else {
            newRealmURL = oldRealmURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("f0.realm")
            defaults.setInteger(0, forKey: "realmFileNum")
        }

        let realm = try! Realm(fileURL: oldRealmURL)

        do {
            try realm.writeCopyToURL(newRealmURL)
        } catch {
        }

        var config = Realm.Configuration()
        config.fileURL = newRealmURL
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

        try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(oldRealmURL)
    }

    func viewWillEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification?) {
        compactionFile(realmURL!)
        setRealmURL()
        print("realmURL = ",realmURL)
        print("schemaVersionAtURL = ",try! schemaVersionAtURL(realmURL!))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

いくつかRealmとiOSのAPIを勘違いされているところがありましたので修正したコードとともに解説します。

まず、Realmファイルのコンパクションを起動中に何度も行うのは、正しく実行するのが難しいので起動時に１度だけにしてください。

Realmのファイルをコピーして再読み込みするのはRealmのインスタンスが全てのスレッドで全て解放されていることを保証する必要があります。それを起動中に行うのは大変です。

コンパクションの処理を少し直して、AppDelegateで起動時に１度だけ呼ぶようにしました。ご覧ください。

また、元の処理では、`Realm.Configuration`を何度も新しく作って、その度に`Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration`に代入していますが、これは間違いです。

`Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration`に代入すると、それが既定の設定になり、`try! Realm()`を呼んだ時にはいつでも`defaultConfiguration`が使われるようになります。
そのことにより、何度も同じ設定をしたり、`Configuration`オブジェクトを渡して回らなくて済む、というものです。

元のコードではいろいろなメソッドを呼ぶたびに新しく`Configuration`が作られて、`defaultConfiguration`に代入されているので、その度に`try! Realm()`で使われる設定が変わってしまいます。
マイグレーションが正しく行われなかったりするのはそのためです。デフォルトの設定がコロコロ変わっているので、Realmをインスタンス化するタイミングによって、どのファイルが使われるのかが変わっているためです。

`defaultConfiguration`も基本的には最初に１度だけ設定して、あとは単に`try! Realm()`を呼ぶことで全て同じ設定を使えるようにするのが適切ですので、そのように変更しました。

最後に、これはRealmと関係ないですが、iOSは標準で、`UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`という通知を送信しています。そのため、わざわざ`AppDelegate`の`applicationWillEnterForeground()`メソッドで通知を送り直す必要はありません。ただ`UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`の通知を受ければいいです。

#### AppDelegate.swift

```
func setupRealm() {
    let defaultConfig = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration

    let realmFileURL = defaultConfig.fileURL!.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("f0.realm")

    var config = defaultConfig
    config.fileURL = realmFileURL
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

    setupMigration()
    compaction()
}

func setupMigration() {
    var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
    config.schemaVersion = 1
    config.migrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {

        }
    }
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
}

func compaction() {
    let config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration

    let realmFileURL = config.fileURL!
    let copyFileURL = realmFileURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("f1.realm")

    let fileManager = NSFileManager()
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(realmFileURL.path!) {
        autoreleasepool {
            do {
                let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
                try realm.writeCopyToURL(copyFileURL)
            } catch {
                let _ = try? fileManager.removeItemAtURL(realmFileURL)
            }
        }

        let _ = try? fileManager.removeItemAtURL(realmFileURL)
        let _ = try? fileManager.moveItemAtURL(copyFileURL, toURL: realmFileURL)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    setupRealm()
    return true
}
```

#### ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var realmURL:NSURL?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // UIApplicationは標準で
        // UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotificationなどの
        // 通知を送信している
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.viewWillEnterForeground(_:)), name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

        let realm = try! Realm()

        let rlm = event()
        rlm.eventID = 0
        rlm.eventTitle = "First Title"
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(rlm, update: true)
        }

        print(realm.objects(event))
    }

    func viewWillEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification?) {
        // コンパクションをアプリケーションの動作中に
        // 正しく行うのは難しいのでは起動時に１度だけにする
    }
}
```

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございました。より理解を深めることができました。

Answer (score 0):

```
Property 'hoge' has been added to latest object model.
```

上記のメッセージはモデルの定義を変更したのにもかかわらず、マイグレーションが正しく行われていないことを示しています。
モデルの定義を変更した場合に、マイグレーションを行うことはプログラマの責任ですので、エラーとして例外が発生し、アプリケーションはクラッシュします。

実際の挙動としては、アプリケーションをアップデートしたら起動時にクラッシュするようになってしまうので、ユーザーがアプリケーションをいったん消して、再インストールしてくれれば、古いデータが消えるので新しいバージョンをまた使えるようになりますが、起動しなくなったことで、アプリを削除して使わなくなってしまう恐れもあります。

正しい実装としては、エラーが起こらないように修正することです。

マイグレーション処理を書いたということですが、それが間違っています。
スキーマバージョンを上げるのを忘れているはずです。

その辺りのコードを見せてもらえますか？

Realmでデータモデルを変更した場合は、1.スキーマバージョンを前回より大きい値に増加させる、2.（必要に応じて）データ移行のためマイグレーション処理を書く、という処理が必要です。

Realm Swift/Objective-Cにはオートマイグレーションがあるので、プロパティを統合・分割するなどがなく、単なるプロパティの追加・削除の場合は2は必要ありません。単にスキーマバージョンを上げるだけでOKです。

Comment: 単純にプロパティを追加しただけのサンプルコードを試しているのですが、configの箇所はドキュメントの内容をそのまま記述しいて、これは他にも記述が必要なのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @marc マイグレーションの処理としてはそれで合っています。おそらくスキーマバージョンがすでに1になっています。意図してか、操作ミスかわかりませんが、１度モデルを変更した際にスキーマバージョン0→1のマイグレーションが実行され、現在はスキーマバージョンが1の状態なのだと思います。`schemaVersion: 1`の部分はマイグレーションのたびに2、3、と前より大きい値に増加させなければなりません。

Comment: 先ほどのコードですが新規のプロジェクトで試したもので、schemaVersion: 0の状態でビルドし、その後schemaVersion: 1に設定、プロパティdynamic var hoge = 0を追加して再ビルドでエラーがでなくなりました。

同じような手順で開発しているプロジェクトで試したのですが、やはりエラーが出ていました。色々と探った結果、このスキーマバージョンってのはdefault.realmのファイルの事を指しているのかなという結論に至りました。

もしそうなら、default.realmではなくwriteCopyToURLで別のファイル名で使用しているので、それを指定すればいいのかなと思いましたが、そのやり方とかはありますでしょうか？
Configurationの中に使用しているファイル名を指定するとか、そういった感じでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @marc `Configuration`には`fileURL`というプロパティがあり、ファイルの保存場所またはどのファイルを開くか、を指定することができます。が、おそらくRealmの使い方をどこか勘違いされているところがあると思いますので、さらにRealmを利用している部分の全体的なコードを見せていただけますか？

Comment: 整理したサンプルコードを追加しました。Realm(fileURL: realmURL!)の箇所が原因だったようで、Realm()に変更したらエラーが出なくなりました。

Comment: ちょっと使い方が間違っていますね。`defaultConfiguration`は`Realm()`を呼んだ時にその設定を使うようにするためのものなので、`defaultConfiguration`をコロコロ変更したり、`defaultConfiguration`でパスを設定しているのに、`Realm(fileURL: realmURL!)`としてパスを与えるのはおかしいです。あとコンパクションを起動中に正しく行うのは難しいので起動時に１度だけにしてください。いろいろ直したコードを別の回答としてあげました。ご覧ください。